# Android Passing the value of Countdown Timer for 2 Activities or more

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I'm trying to pass the countdownTimer value from the activity 1 to the activity 2 and start the countdown Timer in the activity 2 from the value that got from the activity 1 , But I didn't know how to make the starting point for the timer in the activity 2 as a variable, here is my code for activity 1

```
    new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

        }
        public void onFinish() {
            tv.setText("done!");
        }
     }.start();

    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page2.class);
            i.putExtra("timervalue", tv.getText());
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });
```

and here is the code in activity 2

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();  
    long value = Long.parseLong(bundle.getString("timervalue"));
    new CountDownTimer(value, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            tv.setText("done!");
        }
     }.start();
```

I also tried to make activity 2 like this by using Intet instead of Bundle

```
    Intent results = this.getIntent();
    String s = results.getExtras().getString("timervalue");
    long value = Long.parseLong(s);

    new CountDownTimer(value, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            tv.setText("done!");
        }
     }.start();
```

I think the error I have when I putExtra and getExtra But I'm not sure ,I'm really beginner in java So Please Any Help...
Thanks Alot

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper code

in Activity1

```
long remainingtime;
```

And under onCreate

```
 new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Counter.setText("Time left: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                remainingtime=millisUntilFinished;
        }

        public void onFinish() {
        Counter.setText("done!");
    }}.start();  



public void onClick(View v) {

Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);

   Bundle timetransfer=new Bundle();
    timetransfer.putLong("timer", remainingtime);
        i.putExtras(timetransfer);
```

Activity2

```
Under onCreate



Bundle timetransfer = getIntent().getExtras();

                long time =timetransfer.getLong("timer");


        new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long time) {
                Counter2.setText("Time Left: " time / 1000);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                Counter2.setText("Time is UP!");

                finish();    }

         }.start();
```

You must erase this part:

```
long_remaingtime=millisUntilFinished / 1000;
```

and put just

```
long_remaingtime=millisUntilFinished;
```

because in your case you have divided around 20000(millisUntilFinished) with 1000 and      you get around 20 seconds depending on time passed,
and then below that you have put code that divides this number by 1000 again. So in the  next activity you automatically get an error that time has passed.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are passing `"seconds remaining: "+...` to next Activity and trying to parse it to Long means you will get `NumberFormatException` in next Activity . use a extra variable to pass `CountDownTimer` renaming time to next Activity as :

```
public long long_remaingtime=20L;
 new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            long_remaingtime=millisUntilFinished / 1000; //<<< 
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            tv.setText("done!");
            long_remaingtime=20L; //<< set default here
        }
     }.start();

    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Page2.class);
            i.putExtra("timervalue", long_remaingtime);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });
```

and in next Activity get timervalue as :

```
Intent results = this.getIntent();
long value = results.getExtras().getLong("timervalue");
```

Comment: doesn't work ): could you write the whole code for the counter and the next activity please??

Comment: @user2044626 : what problem u are getting ?

Comment: Submitted an edit to variable names and default value assignments that my fix your problem if you copy/pasted @user2044626.